# Use JavaScript to render multiple form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I currently have one form for user to add their work experience. It looks something like this:

**student_experience.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(:user_student, :url => {:controller => 'profile', :action => 'add_student_experience'}) do |f| %>
    <h2>Work experience</h2>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :company_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :job_title %>
        <%= f.text_field :job_title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :job_description %>
        <%= f.text_area :job_description%>
    </p>

    <%= f.submit "Next" %>
```

And in the controller, I have this function:

```
def add_student_experience
    @student_works = StudentWork.create(check_add_student_work_params)

    if @student_works.save
      redirect_to(:controller => 'home', :action => 'index')
    else
        render 'student_experience'
    end
  end
```

What I want to achieve is having one button in the view, to add more forms for user just in case if they have multiple work experience. How do I achieve that? What changes should I made in the controller to handle multiple forms? Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for coccoon gem: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: Try installing [gem "cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)" or using [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the cocoon gem. It's easy and will save you a lot of time.

Here's a detailed description on how to implement cocoon in your case.

**student_exerience.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(:user_student, :url => {:controller => 'profile', :action => 'add_student_experience'}) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :company_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
        <%= f.label :job_title %>
        <%= f.text_field :job_title %>
        <%= f.label :job_description %>
        <%= f.text_area :job_description%>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add experience', f, :experiences %>

    <%= f.submit "Next" %>
```

Create a new partial named `_experience_fields.html.erb` in the same folder as your `student_experience.html.erb` view.

**_experience_fields.html.erb**

```
    <%= f.label :company_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
    <%= f.label :job_title %>
    <%= f.text_field :job_title %>
    <%= f.label :job_description %>
    <%= f.text_area :job_description%>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f%>
```

Don't forget to import cocoon in your `application.js` file `//= require cocoon`